# C - Sockets. client: connect: No such file or directory

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to set up a socket connection between a client and server where server creates socket and reads from it and client writes data to a server.  Here is my code:

```
//server.c  
/* a server in the unix domain.*/
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SOCKETNAME "mynewsocket"
int main(void){
    char buffer[1024];
    int n, sock , nsock;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_un name;

    if((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0){
        perror("server: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&name, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    name.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(name.sun_path, SOCKETNAME);
    len = sizeof(name.sun_family) + strlen(name.sun_path);
    unlink ( name.sun_path ) ;
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, SUN_LEN(&name)) < 0) { 
        perror("server: bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sock, 5) < 0) { 
        perror("server: listen"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((nsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, &len)) < 0) {
        perror("server: accept"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    n=read(nsock,buffer,80);
   printf("A connection has been established\n");
   write(1,buffer,n);
   write(nsock,"I got your message\n",19);

    close(nsock);
    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

and client...

```
//client.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SOCKETNAME "mynewsocket"
int main(void){
    char buffer [1024];
    int n, sock, len;
    struct sockaddr_un name;

    if((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0){
        perror("client: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&name, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    name. sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(name.sun_path, SOCKETNAME);
    len = sizeof(name.sun_family) + strlen(name.sun_path);
    unlink ( name.sun_path ) ;
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, SUN_LEN(&name)) < 0) {
        perror("client: connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Please enter your message: ");
   bzero(buffer,82);
   fgets(buffer,80,stdin);
    write(sock,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    n=read(sock,buffer,80);
   printf("The return message was\n");
   write(1,buffer,n);

    close(sock);
    exit(0);

}
```

To run the two programs, compile first and run it like this:

```
./server &
./client
```

When I run the two programs, the server executes fine but the client executes with an error saying `No such file or directory`
Why is that?  What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `./client` Perhaps?

Comment: @EdHeal I forgot to add that in the question :P, however my client still won't run

Comment: Is it in the current directory?

Comment: @EdHeal yes, both files are in the current and same directories.

Comment: `unlink ( name.sun_path ) ;` Why do you unlink? This is the rendez-vous point for client&server!  (the server *could* create it (and unlink it when it exits), but this is not needed)

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you so much, it worked! greatly appreciated! Also, I understand about the unlink now that you explained it

Comment: @wildplasser can you please express why using `unlink()` cause that error?

Comment: AF_UNIX uses the file system as a namespace(instead of  ip-addresses) Internally (most probably) the {dev_id,inodenumber} are used as "key" for the socket/file-descriptor.

Comment: Okay,I edited my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unlink ( name.sun_path ) ;
```

Why do you unlink? This is the rendez-vous point for client&server! The server *could* create this **file** on the file system once it starts running , and unlink it when it exits. (but that is not needed)

The client uses the file to find the server. (te "secret" they share is the location and name of the socket-file.

AF_UNIX uses the file system as a namespace(filenames instead of ip-addresses+portnumbers) Internally, (most probably) the {dev_id,inodenumber} are used as "key" to identify the socket/file-descriptor